# Razor View and HTML text

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to get to grips with Razor, and have hit a basic snag. I generate a small menu based on the users authenticated status. But, I am doing it wrong.

```
<div>
    <a href="/">Home</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; 
    <a href="/">List</a>
    @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        &nbsp;
        &nbsp;
        <a href="/">Upload</a>
        &nbsp;
        &nbsp;
        <a href="/logout" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this image?');">Logout</a>
    }
</div>
```

It doesn't like the HTML within my {} section. I think it expects an HTML tag... Something like `<div>`, but because I am using `&nbsp`, it's not happy. How do I do this?

Additionally, I am trying to handle an image tag. But this is failing dismally.

```
@using GalleryPresentation.Models
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Craig and Melanie's Digital Moments";
}

<br/>
<div style="text-align: center">
    <img src="@Html.Raw(m => m.RandomImageUrl) />
</div>
```

where my model is simply:

```
{
    public class IndexModel
    {
        public string RandomImageUrl { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Razor cannot detect that you are entering HTML mode. Use the special `<text>` Razor tag to indicate you are in HTML mode.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to display content from HTML, you may use for example @Html.Raw() method. So your code migth be

```
     <div>
                        <a href="/">Home</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;  
                        <a href="/">List</a> 
                        @if (Request.IsAuthenticated) 
                        { @Html.Raw("
                            &nbsp; 
                            &nbsp; 
                            <a href="/">Upload</a> 
                            &nbsp; 
                            &nbsp; 
                            <a href="/logout" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this image?');">Logout</a> ")
                        } 
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

nbsp means non breaking space. It is used in html to insert spaces in the middle. Since you are in the middle of a razor code, the compiler doesn't know when you use an html code, at once without a directive. Since it'll give a compile error. This is more like preprocessor directives in c. (if you know #include ). Here you simply have to use the . The correct code will look as follows.

```
  <div>
<a href="/">Home</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; 
<a href="/">List</a>
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <text>
    &nbsp;
    &nbsp;
    </text>
    <a href="/">Upload</a>
    <text>
    &nbsp;
    &nbsp;
    </text>
    <a href="/logout" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this image?');">Logout</a>
}
  </div>
```